# Error while hosting Angular Universal on IIS

Tags: node.js, angular, ssl, iis

I have an Angular Universal/SSR app that I built and published to IIS. When I run localhost with the port number assigned (e.g.: localhost:120) it is working fine. I then configured it to a domain and assigned an SSL certificate. I noticed whenever I assign the SSL certificate it is giving me a Cloudflare Error 520 "Web server is returning an unknown error", however, if I disable the certificate it is working fine.

To further clarify, if I call the url "http://example.com" it is working but if I call the url "https://example.com" it is not working. I looked online a lot and couldn't find any viable solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my server.ts file:

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import 'localstorage-polyfill'

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

  // global['window'] = window;
  // global['document'] = window.document;
  // global['location'] = location;


// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

  const server = express();

  let distFolder: string;
  const path1 = join(process.cwd(), 'projectName/browser');         // Running from the deployed version (production)
  const path2 = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/projectName/browser');    // Running from the source (local development)


  if (existsSync(path1)) {
    distFolder = path1;
  } else {
    distFolder = path2;
  } 

  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: A quick workaround while further investigating 520 errors is to either make the record DNS-only in the Cloudflare DNS app or temporarily pause Cloudflare, contact your hosting provider or site administrator and request a review of your origin web server error logs.

Comment: I tried this once in the past, without success. I asked my hosting provider and he told me that angular universal hosted through NodeJS is unstable and incrementally uses more ram. He suggested to host the angular universal app through asp.net core instead

Comment: I could not wrap my head around why it is not working, so I will try hosting it through asp.net core, is it possible to add it to an already existing project?

Comment: You need more information to troubleshoot your problem, you can also try using failed request tracing to see details about 520 error.